# On what tithi was bhishma pitamah born?

Tags: mahabharata, kurukshetra, kauravas, chandravansh

Bhishma Pitamah died on Bhishma Ashtami in Kurukshetra War.

But at what tithi was bhishma pitamah born?

Please provide answer with reference